# Talend right way to handle transaction

Tags: transactions, etl, talend

I need to handle the transaction in my ETL proces. I am loading some data from file to my databse, and I need to manage commit and rollback. If any row in my file with data has the mistake or the schema is wrong I need to do the rollback, otherwise I need to put data in my databae table and commit the changes. So I prepared the Job, and everything seems to work. But I am begginer with ETL processes, and I wanted to ask, is there a more efficient way to handle this problem?

Here is the Job schema:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a good approach.

Altough I would go into a more general direction. This means that I would activate the "Stop when error" option in the components which try to write into the db.

Then, I would add a general *tLogCatcher* component which would do two things:

- First, roll back the changes with the *tPostgresRollback* component
- Then output the data into a database table, a log file or on the console (wherever you could use this to get into action)
- And then stop the job

Advantage: You could copy this thing into every new job and have automatic error logging without too much hassle. Only the options that component errors will stop the job has to be enabled.

Comment: You should also close the connection. This could become a problem to request a new connection on a loop (because why not) without releasing it. (done in prejob, postjob is simple).

Answer (score 0):

Job looks good by far. I just have one suggestion that you can put tPostgressqlRollback(onComponentError) on tPostgresqlOuput also if this component has some error.